# How to display your own kanban card in calendar view in Odoo 11?

Tags: xml, calendar, odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I am trying to customise the calendar view of the `calendar.event` model, whose code is:

```
<record id="view_calendar_event_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">calendar.event.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar string="Meetings" date_start="start" date_stop="stop" date_delay="duration" all_day="allday"
            display="[name]" color="color_partner_id" attendee="partner_ids" avatar_model="res.partner"
            use_contacts="True" event_open_popup="%(calendar.view_calendar_event_form_popup)s">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="user_id"/>
            <field name="color_partner_id"/>
            <field name="partner_ids"/>
        </calendar>
    </field>
</record>
```

I want to show some new fields and make the background color depend on a new field named `color_confirmed`. The perfect way would be to replace the kanban shown in the calendar view by a customised one. The Odoo documentation (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/views.html#calendar) says the following:

> **templates**
>
> defines the QWeb template calendar-box. Cards definition may be split into multiple templates for clarity which will be rendered once for each record.
>
> The kanban view uses mostly-standard javascript qweb and provides the following context variables:
>
> ...

I am trying to use that **templates** attribute, but I have no idea how, and I was not able to find an example in all the available modules I have downloaded. One of my attempts:

```
<record id="view_calendar_event_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">calendar.event.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_calendar"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//calendar[1]" position="replace">
            <calendar string="Meetings" date_start="start" date_stop="stop" date_delay="duration"
                all_day="allday" display="[color_confirmed]" color="color_confirmed" attendee="partner_ids"
                avatar_model="res.partner" use_contacts="False" event_open_popup="%(calendar.view_calendar_event_form_popup)s" mode="month">
                <field name="name"/>
                <templates>
                    <t t-name="calendar-box">
                        <div class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                            <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                <strong class="oe_partner_heading"><field name="name"/></strong>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>TEST ITEM 1</li>
                                    <li>TEST ITEM 2</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </calendar>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

As expected, it throws a JS error. I have tried several ways and I am wasting a lot of time in such a single task. Does anyone have an idea of how this works? (or a better way to achieve my purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the js error should be because of the `avatar_model`, `use_contacts`, and  `attendee` in the calendar definition. because the calendar is not accepting those values.

if you remove those fields and add your code will work well. here I have rendered your `calendar-box` template

[image: Odoo Calendar view box]

Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have removed those parameters and I still get JS error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined*. If I remove the `templates` tag and its content, it works. Are you sure you cannot use those three parameters? The source calendar view is using them and it works. Can you paste the code you used to obtain the screenshot you show here so I can compare with mine?

Comment: I have realised that I was looking for Odoo 11 documentation while I am working in version 10. Why it was not working makes sense now. I have edited the question. How do you know how to manage in version 10 what you did in the screenshot?

Comment: It is fair that I accept your answer as the right one, since I asked for version 11 and then realised that I needed the answer for version 10. I have just posted what I actually wanted to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426000/how-to-display-your-own-kanban-card-in-calendar-view-in-odoo-10. Do you know the answer?